# How to return the object if no value found otherwise do some looping with condition and return object using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi i have an array of objects like below,

```
const arr_obj = [
    {
        id: '1',
        jobs: [
            {
                completed: false,
                id: '11',
                run: {
                    id: '6',
                    type: 'type1',
               },
            },
            {
                completed: true,
                id: '14',
                run: {
                    id: '17',
                    type: 'type1',
                },

            },
            {
                completed: false,
                id: '12',
                run: {
                    id: '7',
                    type: 'type2',
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        jobs: [
            {
                completed: true,
                id: '13',
                run: {
                    id: '8',
                    type: 'type2',
                },
            },
            {
                completed: true,
                id: '16',
                run: {
                    id: '9',
                    type: 'type1',
                },

            }, 
            {
                completed: true,
                id: '61',
                run: {
                    id: '19',
                    type: 'type1',
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        jobs: [
            {
                completed: false,
                id:'111',
                run: {
                    id: '62',
                    type: 'type1',
                },
            }, 
        ],
    },
 ],
```

Now i have to get ids from arr_obj which matches this arr of ids

const arr_ids = ["1","2"]

and whose runs are of type "type1" and none of the jobs have completed: false

so the expected output is "2"

the below code works,

```
const filtered_arr_obj = arr_obj.filter(obj => {
    if (arr_ids.includes(obj.id)) {
        const jobs = obj.jobs.filter(job => job.run.type === "type1");
        if (jobs.length > 0) {
            return jobs.every(job => job.completed === true);
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
});

let filtered_ids = filtered_arr_obj.map(obj => obj.id);

console.log("filteredIds", filteredIds)  //2
```

Now the problem is if there are no run and run of type "type" for job then i want to also filter the object which has no job run of type "type1"

so consider below example

const arr_obj = [
{
id: '1',
jobs: [
{
completed: false,
id: '11',
run: {
id: '6',
type: 'type1',
},
},
{
completed: true,
id: '14',
run: {
id: '17',
type: 'type1',
},

```
        },
        {
            completed: false,
            id: '12',
            run: {
                id: '7',
                type: 'type2',
            },
        },
    ],
},
{
    id: '2',
    jobs: [
        {
            completed: true,
            id: '13',
            run: {
                id: '8',
                type: 'type2',
            },
        },
        {
            completed: true,
            id: '16',
            run: {
                id: '9',
                type: 'type1',
            },

        }, 
    ],
},
{
    id: '3',
    jobs: [
        {
            completed: false,
            id: '111',
            run: {
                id: '62',
                type: 'type1',
            },
        },
    ],
},
{
    id: '4',
    jobs: [
        {
            completed: true,
            id: '121',
            run: {
                id: '66',
                type: 'type2',
            },
        },
    ],
},
```

],
and

arr_ids = ["1", "2", "4"]
so the expected output is

["2", "4"]
here 4 is also selected because arr_ids has "4" and the object in arr_obj with id "4" has no job run with type "type1".

how can I modify the above code snippet to also include this condition? could someone help me with this? thanks.

I am new to programming and please do answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Looks like when the id is present in the `arr_ids` and if the jobs length is <= 1 then we should filter it , else we are filtering the type1 jobs and checking whether all are completed .

```js
const arr_obj = [
    {
        id: '1',
        jobs: [
            {
                completed: false,
                id: '11',
                run: {
                    id: '6',
                    type: 'type1',
               },
            },
            {
                completed: true,
                id: '14',
                run: {
                    id: '17',
                    type: 'type1',
                },

            },
            {
                completed: false,
                id: '12',
                run: {
                    id: '7',
                    type: 'type2',
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        jobs: [
            {
                completed: true,
                id: '13',
                run: {
                    id: '8',
                    type: 'type2',
                },
            },
            {
                completed: true,
                id: '16',
                run: {
                    id: '9',
                    type: 'type1',
                },

            }, 
            {
                completed: true,
                id: '61',
                run: {
                    id: '19',
                    type: 'type1',
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        jobs: [
            {
                completed: false,
                id:'111',
                run: {
                    id: '62',
                    type: 'type1',
                },
            }, 
        ],
    },
  {
    id: '4',
    jobs: [
        {
            completed: true,
            id: '121',
            run: {
                id: '66',
                type: 'type2',
            },
        },
    ],
},
 ];

const arr_ids = ["1", "2", "4"];

const filtered_arr_obj = arr_obj.filter(obj => {
    if (arr_ids.includes(obj.id)) {
        if(obj.jobs.length <= 1 ){
          return true;
        }
        else {
          const type1jobs = obj.jobs.filter(job => job.run.type === "type1");
          return type1jobs.every(job => job.completed );
        }
    }
    return false;
});

let filtered_ids = filtered_arr_obj.map(obj => obj.id);

console.log("filteredIds", filtered_ids)
```